# Change mod_wsgi from python3.5 to 3.6

Tags: apache2, python-3.5, mod-wsgi, python-3.6

I have a flask app that used to run with python3.5 on apache2.
I am now trying to change it to run on 3.6 (i have sone type hinting in my code that is only supported on 3.6).

 I have installed the module for python3.6, but when tried to restart apache and run my app, it fails.

 When running

```
mod_wsgi-express module-location
```

I have the python3.5 version

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

The same file also existis on my server in python3.6 dir.

I also changed my $PATH to run python3.6 as a default for python.

How can I tell apache to run on python3.6 and not on 3.5?

Comment: Define "it fails". Without details of an error messages or indication of how it fails, it is impossible to guess. Also, have you uninstalled system mod_wsgi from Apache if one was installed? Did you run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to get configuration you should add to Apache configuration to have it load version build using ``pip``? Read https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It fails, meaning, surfing to the site returns "Internal Server Error" and apache log file shows "Compiled for Python/2.7.11." and "Runtime using Python/2.7.12.".
What is the "system mod_wsgi", how can I unistall the specific system mod_wsgi?
I did run mod_wsgi-express module-config, but when trying to add it to the "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" file and restarting the apache, in the apache logs it still looks like it is running python27

Comment: If you are getting no error in error logs, your Python web framework is likely generated the error and not logging it. What web framework are you using? As to Python version, did you uninstall the system mod_wsgi package before integrating ``pip install`` version into Apache configuration.

Comment: I did (`sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi`). Then the module was install via pip . 
After i did, the errors in the apache are describing that flask is running python3.5, and the error is a syntax error (I use type hinting which is only allowed in python3.6+). 
So the issue is that I have two python3 versions but I would like to run over python3.6. Is there a configuration file that I could tell mod_wsgi which python3 version to execute?

Comment: I have also changed symbolic link `python3` to point at 3.6

Comment: When you run ``pip install mod_wsgi``, you need to use ``pip`` from Python 3.6 virtual environment of Python installation. Make sure you are doing that.

Comment: Thanks! looks like the missing piece was configuring the correct python version to the apache configuration.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

WOHA! It's working!
I uninstalled the mod_wsgi (`sudo apt get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi`).
Then, Installed the module via pip specifically to python3.6 (`python3.6 -m pip install mod_wsgi`), but at this point the apache still ran python3.5.
I added to the apache configuration file (in ubunutu 16.4 the file is located at: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` for RHEL/CentOS 7) the followings:
`LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"`

and
`WSGIPythonHome "/usr"` and that did the trick.

I weeped a lot of tears over this issue, finding the `apache2.conf` file etc, so hopefully this will be helpful to anyone.

Comment: Can you check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353284/target-wsgi-script-var-www-backend-backend-wsgi-py-cannot-be-loaded-as-python . I am stuck with this scenario

Comment: where and how shoul I place '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'  for ubuntu?

Comment: I'd advice to use `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load` file instead of changing apache2.conf. There you can just change module's path to one you need and then run  `a2enmod wsgi`  command.

Answer (score 5):

The `LoadModule` solution worked for me.  However, I found it easiest to first ensure 
`a2dismod wsgi` as provided by the default apache2 module.   I spent 3 days looking at various solutions and answers and reviewing Graham's WSGI guide.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in my case is was to remove python 3.6 from Django env and re-install python 3.5 and it worked.