# Apache2 WSGI Flask server using wrong Python Interpreter

Tags: python, flask, apache2, wsgi

When I run my apache2 Flask server on my VPS, I get this error [image]

After checking the error.log file of apache, I found these errors: [image]

As you can see, there is a `SyntaxError` on the first f-string of the code and of course there is a very large amount of `ImportError`'s. I am convinced that the `SyntaxError` is caused by the Python Interpreter mod_wsgi is using. This is how the `app.wsgi` file looks like:

[image]

(The reason I used the project's path is because of the Virtual Enviroment I'm using is inside the project:)

[image]

The `000-default.conf` file:
[image]

I have 3 Python versions installed on the VPS; Python 3.8, Python 3 and Python 2.7

Every project has it's own venv (Virtual Enviroment) installed, as you can see from the 3rd image I provided, the Flask app doesn't use the Python that is in the `/usr/` folder. I don't know what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate any type of help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096859/change-mod-wsgi-from-python3-5-to-3-6 have some hints. Also, the #! part in app.wsgi is used only if the shell read it. If you run python2.7 that script, It will use python2.7 and not your venv python3.

Comment: @Yuri I cant even install mod_wsgi to my python venv, there is no working solution on the internet either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. You can check [this](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/681) GitHub issue.